# Show that $f(x)=0, \forall x \in \left[a, b \right].$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives

If $f \in C\left[a,b \right]$ and $\int_a^b x^nf(x)dx =0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f(x)=0, \forall x \in \left[a, b \right].$

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(P_n)$ be a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$ (this exists by Stone-Weierstrass). We have:

$$\int_a^b|f(x)|^2dx = \left|\int_a^b f(x)\left( f(x) - P_n(x) + P_n(x)\right) dx\right| \le \|f-P_n\|_{\infty} \int_a^b |f(x)| dx \to 0$$

Hence $|f|^2 \equiv 0$, i.e. $f=0$.